# group given list elements using certain criteria

Tags: python

I have a list of 5 polygons as follows:

```
from itertools import compress
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

  polys = [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x000002D634217668>
     <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x000002D634217780>
     <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x000002D6341F9080>
     <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x000002D634217FD0>
     <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x000002D634217F60>]
```

I have to group them into the intersecting polys:

```
results = []
for poly in polys:
    indices = [poly.intersects(p) for p in polys]
    intersect_polys = list(compress(polys, indices))
    results.append(intersect_polys)
```

## Note: poly.intersects returns true if they intersect, otherwise false.That's only the use of shapely here.

EDIT:
Based on comments @Aran-Fey:

In the case of 3 polygons, for example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xN3g.png`[a,b,c]`, it's possible for `b` to intersect with `both a and c` even if `a` and `c` don't intersect.

The result would be:

```
[[b,c], [b,a]]
```

I have to find all such groups.
Since order of polygons is not important, should also remove the duplicate groups (containing same polygons)

Comment: So if you have 3 polygons `[a, b, c]`, and `a` doesn't intersect `c`, but `b` intersects both `a` and `c`, the result should be `[[a, b, c]]`?

Comment: It's possible for `b` to intersect with both `a` and `c` even if `a` and `c` don't intersect. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ekTokK9.png) for example.

Comment: thanks for your picture. yes, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: so result would be [[b,c], [b,a]]

Comment: so in my question, i have to find all such groups

Comment: Ok. You should [edit] all that information into the question though, otherwise you risk it being closed.

Comment: okay, i'm editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could think of was to iterate over all polygons, and then loop over all the *other* polygons to find intersections. (Which means the algorithm has a quadratic run time complexity.) Inefficient, but it gets the job done.

```
result = []
for i, shape in enumerate(polys):
    intersected_shapes = [poly for poly in polys[i+1:] if shape.intersects(poly)]
    if intersected_shapes:
        intersected_shapes.append(shape)
        result.append(intersected_shapes)
```

With the input `[a, b, c]` from the question ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xN3g.png)), this produces the output:

```
[[b, a], [c, b]]
```

Comment: thanks, btw there may be chance of getting duplicate groups? Since order of polys is not important, should remove duplicate groups (containing same polygons)

Comment: @ian I don't think there's a chance of that happening, no. The code only loops over the polygons that appear later in the list (for example `a` iterates over `b` and `c`, but `b` only iterates over `c`, and `c` doesn't iterate at all), so I don't see how any duplicates could be created.